# How to query all chains which contain some node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this type of graph:

`(a)->[r1]->(b)-[r1]->(c)->[r1]->(d)`... .Also every node may have additional one or several relationships `r2`, for example:

```
(b)->[r2]->(G)
```

`(b)->[r2]->(K)` and so on, or:

```
(c)->[r2]->(G)
```

`(c)->[r2]->(K)`.

If I use query like this:

```
MATCH (n1)-[r]->(n2)-[r1]->(n3)-[r2]->(n4)-[r3]->(n5)-[r4]->(n6)
WHERE n1.property = "`DEF9747D6`"
RETURN r,r1,r2,r3,r4,n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6 LIMIT 10
```

It returns only specified node and relationship from n1 to n6, but the problem that I do not know before head how many nodes a chain contains.

So I need a query, which may return all chains and relationships even if I specify a property node in the middle. For example:

I specify some (`c.Property`) and query must return all chains form (a) and to end and all relationships `r1` and `r2`.

Can you please help me with this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below query should work:

```
MATCH p = (n1)-[:n1|:n2*]->()
WHERE n1.property = "`DEF9747D6`"
RETURN relationships(p), nodes(p)
LIMIT 10
```

This query uses a [variable-length pattern matching](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength) to `MATCH` all patterns starting from a node with n1.property = "`DEF9747D6`" transversing across relationships of type `:n1` and `:n2`. The functions [relationships()](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-relationships) and [nodes()](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-nodes) are used to return all relationships and nodes from each path.

*Tip: when working with relationship types, remember to add `:` before the name of the type. That is: use `:n1` instead of `n1`.*

Comment: Excellent, dear Bruno Peres! This search work pretty well for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @Andrew you are welcome! If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Little modification which work for me:


MATCH p = ()-[*]->(n1)-[*]->()
WHERE n1.property = "`DEF9747D6`"
RETURN relationships(p), nodes(p)
LIMIT 100